# How to use WSGI to reroute a user from http to https

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, https, webapp2

**Original Question**

---

App Engine SDK 1.6.5
Python 2.7
webapp2

I have implemented webapp2 schemes to secure pages to https.  The issue is that when a user goes to say http:// site/login instead of https:// site/login they get a 404 error due to the schemes not recognising the route.

example main.py

```
#  Libraries
import webapp2

#  Local Controllers
from controllers.HomeHandler import HomeHandler
from controllers.LoginHandler import LoginHandler

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/', HomeHandler),
    webapp2.Route(r'/login', LoginHandler, schemes=['https'], name='login')
], debug=True)
```

I have added another route / controller below the https route to catch http requests:
`webapp2.Route(r'/login', RouteLogin)`

RouteLogin.py

```
#  Libraries
import webapp2

class RouteLogin(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('https://site.appspot.com/login')
```

This works, but it seems there should be a better way to do this.  Like using htaccess on Apache web server.  This is too much like a hack for my liking.  I really don't like hard coded URLs in my code.  Not to mention that it is 2 requests which for login isn't a big deal, but there could be other examples where it ends up costing too much.

NOTE 1:  If you are looking at this solution be aware that using the HTTPS schemes also means that you will be unable to use the dev console without deleting the SCHEME or configuring a variable that you set for dev.

NOTE 2:  I was able to get a programatic way to serve HTTPS instead of HTTP.  I was on the right track with the comment below but it needs an argument.

`webapp2.uri_for('login', _scheme='https')`
This will give you the correct https://someapp.appspot.com/login url.  It unfortunately doesn't take care of my main problem of how to handle people typing the url into the address bar without https and receiving an error unless I use the hack above.  So I am still looking for the WSGI way to route income requests to HTPPS.

Edits:  Added Note 1 and clarified the title, I thought it was apparent that I was using WSGI from the source and not CGI.

Comment: While this is a side problem using `webapp2.uri_for('login')` doesn't generate https as the URL either.  So it leaves me trying to tackle the full problem still.  If the User doesn't initiate https App Engine plugs along in HTTP and errors on /login since it is still http unless I hard code the link or use my hack above.

Comment: How about doing a string substitution to replace http with https? It's not the best solution, but at least that way you don't have to hard-code the entire URL

Comment: Please post the answer to your question as an answer, whether you accept it or not (you can accept your own answer, especially instead of a wrong answer, as one of your comments below suggests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code I used in testing for this question.

Note: The development Web Server (as of this writing v1.6.5) doesn't support https so your WSGI routes will need the schemes removed to work in the development environment.  You can add them back before deployment or create an variable to set the scheme that checks the environment as I did below.

You can get App Engine Python to reroute the request by defining app.yaml as:
app.yaml

```
application: cgi-vs-wsgi
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest

handlers:

- url: /profile
  script: main.app
  secure: always

- url: /login
  script: main.app
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Then in main.py you can declare your WSGI Handlers as normal like:

main.py

```
import webapp2
import os

# Models
from models.Shout import Shout

# Controllers
from controllers.HomeHandler import HomeHandler
from controllers.LoginHandler import LoginHandler
from controllers.ProfileHandler import ProfileHandler

if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development'):
    app_scheme = 'http'
else:
    app_scheme = 'https'

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/login', LoginHandler, name='login', schemes=[app_scheme]),
    webapp2.Route(r'/profile', ProfileHandler, name='profile', schemes=[app_scheme]),
    webapp2.Route(r'/', HomeHandler)
], debug=True)
```

I have uploaded the code for this app to my [AE-BaseApp GitHub](https://github.com/AE-BaseApp/http-to-https) please feel free to download and use this in your applications.  The code is licensed Apache License 2.0.

Answer (score 8):

Set the URLs in app.yaml, rather than in code. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Secure_URLs

For example:

```
handlers:

- url: /foo/.*
  script: accounts.py
  secure: always
```

This will redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: Unfortunately that is a CGI method and is incompatible with using [Thread Safe](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests), or that is how I would have done it from the start.  I am looking for the WSGI method of doing that if there is one.

Comment: Where in that documentation does it say or imply that `secure` is incompatible with `threadsafe`? It doesn't, and it's not.

Comment: @Daniel-Roseman I [quote](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27#Configuring_WSGI_Script_Handlers) "Warning! If you plan to use concurrent requests, you must use WSGI handlers."  If you put CGI handlers in app.yaml when you declare threadsafe you get the following error.
`Fatal error when loading application configuration:  `
`Invalid object:`  
`threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: main.py`

Comment: The "secure: always" option works with WSGI handlers too.  Note that you can have multiple clauses with the same handler (main.app, I presume) but different url patterns and different options, as long as the most general pattern comes last.

Comment: The above answer from @WilfredHughes is wrong if you use it you will get the error I posted. I worked on this trying to get it to work since @GuidoVanRossum says it does, and if anybody knows it is certainly him. The issue is `script: main.py` versus `script: main.app`. When using .py it is interpreted as CGI vs .app as WSGI.  Or at least in my case every time I used the .py extension I get that CGI error above.