# Can I configure all URLs to be secure on Google App Engine (python app) with just one setting?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Is it possible in the app.yaml to make sure that all requests to my app on http get redirected to https without having to specify secure: always for every url endpoint in my app.

Currently I am doing this:

```
url: /users/login
script: users_handler.app
secure: always

url: /signin
script: authentication.app
secure: always

url: /users/logout
script: users_handler.app
secure: always
```

But as new urls are added, its risky as a developer might forget to specify secure always. I would prefer to just specify a global setting that applies to all urls in my app.

Answer (score 1):

If you don not want to use secure in your app.yaml you can accomplish this with webapp2. 
https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#restricting-uri-schemes

And here is a working code eaxmple: [How to use WSGI to reroute a user from http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804873/how-to-use-wsgi-to-reroute-a-user-from-http-to-https#10845046)

Comment: The first link is dead :(

Answer (score 1):

I feel like archaeologist, but nonetheless I'll share my findings.

All it has to be made is to add this into **app.yaml**:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto
```

There is even [documentation example with that case](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_script). It's exactly the same as mine, but I removed redirection.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that is possible. However, I think you can mitigate the problem by restructuring the URLs you have defined in your app.yaml.

The URLs is matched against handlers in your app.yaml starting from the top. So you should specify your one-off URLs and then at the bottom have a catch all setting that routes all URLs that didn't match the other settings to your default handler. You application should then display 404 pages etc. for URLs that don't exist in your application.

Something like this would work:

```
- url: /signin
  script: authentication.app
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: users_handler.app
  secure: always
```

This way you only have to specify a couple handlers for your application and you are much less likely to miss setting secure:always when adding a new URL or setting.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This solution will create a new handler to catch 404 errors for pages that don't exist, (and ensure they're served over SSL) but this "catch all" handler doesn't do what the question asked, which is secure all of the other, existing handlers within the app.