# Redirect http to https for certain domains in webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

We use Google appengine namespaces for a mutli-tenant application. Each tenant has a different domain. Some of the domains need to have ssl enabled but some do not require ssl. For the domains that do require ssl, I'd like all old http links to redirect to their https equivalent.

If we set `secure: always` in app.yaml, then the domains that do not require ssl (domains that don't have certificates) won't work as all requests are redirect to https.

I assume I need to handle the redirect to https in webapp routing, depending on the domain requested. 
I've tried the "app_scheme" approach outlined here [How to use WSGI to reroute a user from http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804873/how-to-use-wsgi-to-reroute-a-user-from-http-to-https) but that doesn't handle redirects to https if accessing via http.

Is there a way to handle redirect without re-writing all the DomainRoutes?

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach: you could have 2 apps, one for the http domains and one for the https domains, sharing the same app code except for the `secure: always` settings in the `.yaml` config files (achievable with a simple VCS repo branching strategy). No rule re-writing required.

The 1st app is your current app unchanged, serving all http-only domains.

The 2nd app is a clone of your existing app, with `secure: always` added in `app.yaml`. It will serve all https domains.

You'd need to remove the https domains from the domain mappings of your 1st app and place them in the domain mapping of your 2nd app.

You *may* also need to copy/move any datastore data pertinent to the https-only domains to the 2nd app since AFAIK the apps can't share the same datastore (it *might* be possible to share cloud storage between the 2 apps). Not 100% sure, I didn't yet attempt to share data between different apps.

Comment: So are you saying they're hosted in 2 different appengine accounts or are they just 2 different modules?

Comment: I meant 2 different apps - minimal changes required to the existing code because the apps are independent. It could work with modules as well, but that'll likely require more changes to avoid operational conflicts due to overlapping functionality - modules still share some of the GAE services.

Comment: ok, so 2 different apps isn't an option (as there are loads of different apps I'd need to deploy to make this solution work). Modules could possibly work. So in dispatch.yaml would you setup each different domains? Also doesn't seem like the best solution.

Comment: No, just 2 apps, I'll update the answer. Yes, with modules you'd need each domain explicitly routed in `dispatch.yaml`, another disadvantage of a modules-based approach.